# Instilling a sense of something

Tags: grammaticality

I do not get the meaning of the bold text [in the following sentence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/software-entropy):

> One broken window, left unrepaired for any substantial length of time,
>   instills in the inhabitants of the building a sense of abandonment—**a
>   sense that the powers that be don’t care about the building**.

I could find two entries in the [dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-cobuild/have%20a%20sense%20that/get%20a%20sense%20that) regarding having a sense of something:

- If you have **a sense that something is the case**, you think that it
  is the case, although you may not have firm, clear evidence for this
  belief.
- have a sense that/get a sense that
  *Do you have the sense that you are loved by the public?*

But the above sentence I quoted is unlike the dictionary examples and does not make any sense to me. If it was something like "**a sense of being don't care about the building**", that would have some meaning to me. If it is grammatically correct, please somebody explain it to me.

Comment: "Sense" = "feeling" or "belief". If the owners and managers of the building don't repair their damaged building, it's easy for outsiders and residents of the building to _feel_ or _believe_ that the owners and managers don't care about the building.

Comment: The ambiguity was the result of two subsequent "that"s there. Knowing the meaning of "The powers that be" made everything clear.

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from the question, but I see your point. If you don't know that idiom, then the sentence **is** confusing.

Comment: I'm voting to close as General Reference on the grounds that OP only asked this question because he didn't understand the idiom *the powers that be.* (Commonly,[TPTB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_powers_that_be_(phrase) here on ELU) At the very least, the title is hopelessly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The powers that be" is a phrase used to describe higher up people with more power than yourself. Like a manager, etc.
So in this example it may be that the building's owners/management are "the powers that be" who don't care much about the building's maintenance.

Comment: And for which we are indebted to William Tyndale.